# How to swing knife with C# unity script

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have a humanoid model (player) and it walks correctly and he is being followed by an enemy. Now I want to

1) add ' knife ' to my player

2) When hit space bar button, the player should take out knife

3) When hit MouseLeft Click, it should attack the enemy (if knife is out, else no attack)

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed in this , Can you advise the way how should i go and is there any script which can be used to do this task

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code you have tried, and specifically what the problem is.  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I hope this could help you out!,but make sure you have the knife gameObject attached with the player's hand or you can spawn using instantiate() method

```
public GameObject Knife;  //  knife 3d model

public bool isKnifeActive;  // bool to check knife is there in hand or not

void Start()
{
    Knife.SetActive (false);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Knife.SetActive = true;
        isKnifeActive = true;
        StartCoroutine ("Knifedisable");
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        playerAttack ();
    }
}

public void playerAttack()
{
    if (isKnifeActive) 
    {
        //********** play your knife - player attacking animation here ***************//
    }
}

IEnumerator Knifedisable()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);
    Knife.SetActive = false;
    isKnifeActive = false;
}

void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    //********* write your opponent health reducing code here *************//
}
```

trigger the animation and write your way of logic in reducing enemy's health,but for trigger event you must have collider and Rigidbody attached to the same gameObject and make sure you have checked isTrigger field Enjoy!!

Comment: Thanks, got an idea from this.. great